# Use Main form code to open a UserControl from another UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, access-modifiers

I am using UserControl as button inside a FlowLayoutPanel as it contains text and other information. By clicking on the UserControl inside the FlowLayoutPanel, it's supposed to show form in my Main form.

Here is UserControl example:

```
private void SelectuCControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Main OP = new Main();
    OP.ucControl.Show();
    OP.ucControl.BringToFront();
}
```

In `Main` Form, the access modifier of `ucControl` (UserControl) is set to Public.
But when I click, nothing happens and CPU and Memory getting higher with every click. Something is happening in background but I can't see it.

I also tried to do it in different way.
Here is example of another way of unsuccessful try.

Main form:

```
public void ShowUC()
{
    ucControl.Show();
    ucControl.BringToFront();
}
```

and in UserControl:

```
private void SelectContacts_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Main OP = new Main();
    OP.ShowUC();
}
```

But still, same thing.
Do you know how can I show a UserControl that is hidden in Main Form by clicking on another UserControl that is located in the FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: I should Add that originaly my user control that I wan't to show is hidden in Main form.

Comment: You keep on creating a `new Main()` on each click. That `Main` is not the existing Main Form. it's a new one, thus calling the Public method has no result. If `Main` is the parent Form of the UserControl, you have its reference already there: `[UserControl].ParentForm` or `[UserControl].FindForm()`. Both will return the current instance of the container Form.

Comment: But, from you're showing here, it's not really clear which UserControl you're trying to show, which is its Parent Form and what part `SelectuCControl` and `SelectContacts` should be playing.

Comment: So I have Main Form that has multiple User Controls. 
Each User Control is configured differently.

One User control has flowLayout and inside of that flowLayout I have User Control buttons. And when you click on that User control inside of FlowLayout, it should run command/code

ucControl.Show();
ucControl.BringToFront();

Inside my Main Form

Answer (score 0):

If you write the following code:

```
Main x = new Main();
Main y = new Main();
```

...then `x` and `y` are not the same `Main` - they are two separate instances of `Main`.

If you interact or change anything about `x` then it has no impact whatsoever on `y`.

If you do want `y` to be the same instance, then you need to do something like this:

```
Main x = new Main();
Main y = x;
```

In your code you need to find a way to do something like this:

```
public Main OP;
private void SelectuCControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    OP.ucControl.Show();
    OP.ucControl.BringToFront();
}
```

Now you can set `OP` to the same instance of `Main` when you set up the `UserControl`.

Comment: To make it more clear, this is what I have.

So I have Main Form that has multiple User Controls. Each User Control is configured differently. One User control has flowLayout and inside of that flowLayout I have User Control buttons. And when you click on that User control inside of FlowLayout, it should run command/code ucControl.Show(); ucControl.BringToFront(); Inside my Main Form

Comment: I've got error: 

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: That's why my last paragraph in my answer said that you needed to set the reference yourself.

Comment: I am very new in C# could you tell me how to do it please?

Comment: @Mark - When you're in your existing instance of `Main` you would do something like `var uc = new UserControl(); uc.OP = this;`. I can't say exactly what you need to do because you didn't provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: I still receive that OP was null.

Comment: @Mark - Sorry, but you'll need to add the new code **to the end of your question** for me to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
All I had to do is to add this command in my UserControl that I am using as button.

```
        Main OP = (Main)ParentForm;
        OP.ShowUC();
```